# Prove a transformation is a variational symmetry?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, variational-calculus

My question:

**How to prove** the family of transformations of the $(t,q)$ space, given by $(t,q) \to (t,U(\epsilon)q)$, where $U(\epsilon) \in SO(3)$, is a **variational symmetry**?

**So it depends on $L$ by the definition of variatonal symmetry**. In my case, suppose $L(Mq,M \dot q)=L(q,\dot q)$, where $q=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $M \in SO(3)$. It means after rotation, $L$ doesn't change.

**Explanation of variational symmetry:**

"variational symmetry" means after transformation, the value of integration stays the same.

Thanks so much! Attached is definition of variational symmetry.

[image]

Comment: $\uparrow$ Of which $L$?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry about that. I edited the question. If something is not right. Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: and where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Phoenix87 My problem is in the first line, prove that $(t,q) \to (t, U(\epsilon)q) $ is a variational symmetry. I will edit the question to make it clear. Thanks!

Comment: isn't it enough to assume that $q$ is an extremal, and therefore the time derivative of $U(\epsilon)q$ is $U(\epsilon)\dot q$?

Comment: @Phoenix87 So does that mean $L(t,q, \dot q)=L(t, U(\epsilon) q, U(\epsilon) \dot q)$? Then how to deal with the integral upper and lower limit? Does them stay the same?

Comment: you are not changing the time variable with your family of transformations.